# Meaning of 'set of well-ordered sequences'

Tags: sequences-and-series, commutative-algebra, modules, well-orders, injective-module

I'm trying to make sense of a construction of a module given in the following research paper: [*A New Construction of the Injective Hull*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-mathematical-bulletin/article/new-construction-of-the-injective-hull/63C105DC2199DB9D2D8BC343D47B8B4B), Fleischer, 1968.

On the second page, a module $F$ is constructed, with the definition of the underlying set being 'the set of those **well-ordered sequences** $\{f_\alpha\}$ of ...', which seems unclear to me.

What is a 'well-ordered sequence'? My understanding of a sequence is that it is a function with domain $\mathbb{N}$. Of course $\mathbb{N}$ is well-ordered, but there is no need to refer to a sequence as well-ordered. So I guess this is referring to something slightly different, but I do not see any well-ordering going on anywhere so am at a loss. What might this be referring to?

Comment: If you're working with the Axiom of Choice, you can get make a well ordered set out of anything, so I assume this text isn't using AC?

Comment: It's quite an old paper, but I imagine it would still say so if AC was not assumed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume a well-ordered sequence in $F$ means a map $\alpha \to F; a \mapsto f_a$ for some well-ordered set $\alpha$.

For $\alpha = \mathbb N$ we get a normal sequence. For $\alpha$ finite we get a finite set of elements of $F$. For $\alpha = \omega_1$ we get an  $\omega_1$-sequence which is like a normal sequence but longer.

The set of all well-ordered sequences includes all of the above.

There are cardinality problems with defining such a set, since you quickly end up considering the set of all sets. But for any given application it is often fine to only consider all well-ordered sets below some given cardinality depending on the size of the other objects under consideration.

Comment: Are you saying that a 'well-ordered sequence' in $F$ then would likely mean a pair $(\alpha,f)$, where $\alpha$ is a well-ordered set and $f:\alpha\to F$ is any function (with appropriate restrictions on the cardinality of the sets $\alpha$)?

Comment: That is the idea. You only need the cardinality restrictions if you want to consider the set of all such sequences.

Comment: one can wlog restrict the cardinality of the index set to any upper bound on the cardinality of a strictly decreasing sequence ideals of $R$. eg $\omega$ if $R$ is Noetherian.

Comment: In general there are no more than $2^{2^{|R|}}$ of those sequences. This is a stupid bound. It's the number of collections of subsets of $|R|$. But it is good enough for the cardinality problems.

Comment: @OlivierRoche Maybe it doesn't make any difference, but the specific ring I am working with is not Noetherian (I am trying to apply the construction described in the paper to find injective modules over a specific local ring)

Comment: @user829347 Well I meant this : for any ring $R$, the sets indexing a strictly decreasing sequence of ideals of $R$ can't become arbitrarily large. This holds even if $R$ is not Noetherian.

Comment: Oh, and $f_\alpha$ is not a function, just an element of $F$. A sequence indexed by $\beta$ is just the data of a given $f_\alpha \in F$ for each $\alpha < \beta$, one writes $(f_\alpha)_{\alpha < \beta}$ for short.

Comment: @Daron I think that you meant the straightforward upper bound $|F|^{2^|F|}$

Comment: @Daron **CORRECTION** I think that you meant the straightforward upper bound $|2^F|$ since there is at most one way that a subset of $F$ can be indexed in such a way that we get a well ordered-sequence-etc.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, a **well ordered sequence** is just a sequence $(f_\beta)_{\beta < \gamma}$ where $\gamma$ is a well ordered set (and hence $\gamma$ is isomorphic to an ordinal so wlog you can assume that $\gamma$ is an ordinal).

NB:

- $\mathbb{N}$, a.k.a $\omega$, is a well ordered set, hence every sequence indexed by $\mathbb{N}$ is indeed well ordered.
- Every finite sequence is well ordered.

Comment: So a well-ordered sequence is a pair $(\gamma,f)$, where $\gamma$ is an ordinal and $f:\{\text{ ordinals }<\gamma\}\to F$?

Comment: @user829347 as far as you're concerned, yes